# How to do Inference with Custom Preprocessing and Data Files on Google Cloud ML

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I want to use a model that I have trained for inference on Google Cloud ML. It is a NLP model, and I want my node.js server to interact with the model to get predictions at train time.

I have a process for running inference on the model manually, that I would like to duplicate in the cloud:

1. Use Stanford Core NLP to tokenize my text and generate data files that store my tokenized text.
2. Have the model use those data files, create Tensorflow Examples out of it, and run the model.
3. Have the model print out the predictions.

Here is how I think I can replicate it in the Cloud:

1. Send the text to the cloud using my node.js server.
2. Run my python script to generate the data file. It seems like I will have to do this inside of a custom prediction routine. I'm not sure how I can use Stanford Core NLP here.
3. Save the data file in a bucket in Google Cloud.
4. In the custom prediction routine, load the saved data file and execute the model.

Can anyone tell me if this process is correct? Also, how can I run Stanford CoreNLP on Google Cloud custom prediction routine? Also, is there a way for me to just run command line scripts (for example for creating the data files I have a simple command that I normally just run to create them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom preprocessing method in Python and invoke the Stanford toolkit from there. See this blog and associated sample code for details: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/ai-in-depth-creating-preprocessing-model-serving-affinity-with-custom-online-prediction-on-ai-platform-serving

Comment: How would you store the dictionary that has the mapping from tokenized words to numbers in order to do the inference? Should it be stored somewhere on Google Cloud and gotten every time? If so, how to do that?

Comment: You could do that and read it in each time using tf.gfile.GFile  or you could simply store the vocabulary dictionary as a field of the class.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second option? I'm not sure what you mean by storing the vocabulary dictionary as a field of the class?

Comment: Please see the link above. It links to an example notebook  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/keras/Text%20Classification%20Using%20Keras%20and%20CMLE.ipynb has a self.__tokenizer__ that is a field of the class.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do this an was able to upload the code and set up the model with custom online prediction. However, when trying to make a request to the model from the client, I get `'data: { error: 'Prediction failed: unknown error.' }}` as a response back. The body of my request is `body: '{"instances":"asdfsafd"}',` and I am just using the instances parameter of the prediction variable as my text input on my custom prediction routine. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: your input is incorrect json. see: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request  ... for what your model requires, use saved_model_cli.

Comment: I changed my input to this: `body: '{"instances":["yup that’s great"]}',`, which seems to match this from the doc you linked: `{"instances": ["the quick brown fox", "la bruja le dio"]}`. However, it still doesn't work and has same error. I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: post a new question with the response from saved_model_cli

Comment: I am using the custom prediction routine. So `instances` should be the input my predict function gets right? In my custom prediction routine, my predict function has this signature: `def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):`, and then I get the sentence (which in this case should be "yup that's great") from instances like so: `utterance = nltk.word_tokenize(instances)`, still in the predict function. I then process this sentence and feed it into my model. I'm confident that once I have the sentence the rest of the code works as I tested it locally. Do you see an issue?

Comment: That's how they seem to be doing it in the following link towards the end of the page. They just combine all their text data into an array, pass that array as the body like I did above with instances, and then directly use that as their text input and preprocess it. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/ai-in-depth-creating-preprocessing-model-serving-affinity-with-custom-online-prediction-on-ai-platform-serving

Comment: I posted a question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604407/unknown-error-sending-data-to-google-cloud-ml-custom-prediction-routine