# Unknown Error Sending Data to Google Cloud ML Custom Prediction Routine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to write a custom ML prediction routine on AI Platform to get text data from a client, do some custom preprocessing, pass it into the model, and run the model. I was able to package and deploy this code on Google cloud successfully. However, every time I try to send a request to it from node.js, I get back `data: { error: 'Prediction failed: unknown error.' },`.

Here is my relevant custom prediction routine code. Note that I set `instances` to my text in the client and then tokenize and preprocess it in the custom prediction routine.

```
def __init__(self, model, session, saver, dictionary):
    self.model = model
    self.sess = session

@classmethod
def from_path(cls, model_dir):
    m = Model(learning_rate=0.1)
    session = tf.Session()
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=0)
    saver.restore(session, (os.path.join(model_dir, 'model.ckpt')))
    return cls(m, session)

def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
    utterance = nltk.word_tokenize(instances)
    utterance = self.preprocess_utterance(utterance)

    preds = self.sess.run([self.model['preds'], feed_dict={'input_data': utterance)
    return preds
```

Here is my Node.js code:

```
   text_string = "Hello how are you?"
   google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Authentication failed because of ', err);
            return;
        }
        if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
            var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
            authClient = authClient.createScoped(scopes);
        }
        var request = {
            name: "projects/" + projectId + "/models/classifier",
            resource: {"instances": [message_string]},

            // This is a "request-level" option
            auth: authClient
        };

        machinelearning.projects.predict(request, function (err, result) {

            console.log(result)

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
                res.status(200).send('Hello, world! This is the prediction: ' + JSON.stringify(result)).end();
            }
        });
    });
```

In this code I am just sending the text to the google Cloud model. The request body is:
`body: '{"instances":["Hello how are you?"]}',`

Does anyone have an idea of why it's failing?

If not, then does anyone have any idea of how I can debug this? An unknown error message is not useful at all.

Edit:

Here is the output from `saved_model_cli` with the `--all` option.

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['length_input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: ()
        name: Placeholder_3:0
    inputs['seqlen'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_2:0
    inputs['indicator'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: Placeholder_1:0
    inputs['input_data'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, -1)
        name: Placeholder:0
    inputs['y'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, -1)
        name: Placeholder_4:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['preds'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, -1)
        name: Cast:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Based on this, I should provide this dictionary as input, but it does not work.

`{"instances": [ {
      "input_data": [138, 30, 66],
      "length_input": 1,
      "indicator": [[0, 0]], 
      "seqlen": [3],
      "y": [138, 30, 66]
    }
    ]}`

Comment: please run saved_model_cli on the savedmodel and post what you get

Comment: I can't figure out how to run that on my model as I save it with `tf.train.write_graph(tf.get_default_graph(),...)` and I get an error `Message type "tensorflow.SavedModel" has no field named "node"..`. However, I can tell you what my inputs and outputs are. My inputs are the field `input_data, seqlen, indicator, length_input`. I changed my instances to match this, but it still fails. ```{"instances": [{"input_data": "Hello how are you doing?", "seqlen": [5], "indicator": [1], "length_input": 1}]}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The issue was not the formatting of the input data. Rather it was in NLTK. `NLTK.word_tokenize` was throwing an error because it did not have the data necessary to do the tokenization. I had to upload the data to Google Cloud or use a tokenization method that didn't require any data files to solve this problem.

I don't know why this Google Cloud custom prediction routine software doesn't tell its users the errors that are happening, but through all my efforts it always just returns `Unknown error` whenever something goes wrong. If I had known precisely what the error was, this would have been an easy fix.

Comment: Did you enable "stream logging"? https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict#requesting_logs_for_online_prediction_requests

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
{instances: [
 {"input_data": "hello, how are you?"},
 {"input_data": "who is this?"}
]}
```

but we can confirm if we can look at result of calling saved_model_cli on your SavedModel files.

Comment: Ok, I will post that and try this. But, why do I need my instances dictionary to have the dictionary format of the input of my model (in this case input_data is my input tensor in the model which takes in the text) when I am doing preprocessing first? I don't want the text `hello, how are you?` to be fed into the model, I need to preprocess it first.

Comment: I posted the output from saved_model_cli in the original post.

Comment: The model I have deployed in AI Platform comes from saver.save though, which is not the files I used to generate this saved_model_cli output. I used `tf.saved_model.simple_save` to generate this.

Comment: I saved the model using tf.saved_model.simple_save now and deployed it to the Cloud. I tried the input I pasted above at the end of my original question in the Google Cloud console. I still get Unknown Error. Note that when I run this locally by creating an instance of my custom prediction routine class and then passing just a text string to it as `Instances', I get the correct result. I just don't understand what could be wrong.